# Azure Blob Storage as Source and FTP as destination

Tags: azure, ssis, ftp, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

Is there anyway I can transfer txt files from my Azure Blob Storage to a FTP directly, going serverless?
If possible using SSIS or Azure Data Factory.

Thanks!

Comment: you can also use logic app, it has blob and ftp connectors

Comment: I tried it, I couldn't find the blob storage "blob content" to put on the FTP destination, searched for examples/documentation and didn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: would you like some samples ?

Comment: That would be great @Thomas

Comment: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Azure Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/):

- [Connectors to blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage)
- [Connectors to FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp)

A simple logic app to push a blob to a FTP would be:

[image: Azure LogicApp - Blob to FTP]

Answer (score 1):

SSIS has a lot of connectors that can talk directly to AZURE storage. As for FTP, you may have to use a third party software (WinSCP) that can accomplish uploading of the file to FTP (if the built in FTP Task doesnt accomplish it already). If you are looking to go directly from Azure to FTP, you may have to rely on custom C# code. I am not even sure if that is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "FTP Destination" on SSIS Data Flow. I'm hoping there is a more user friendly alternative than coding it all...

Comment: Use WinSCP. I have used it bunch of times and it works well with SSIS.

Comment: But keep in mind that you will have to land the file somewhere for it to work.

Comment: I need a serverless solution, but I will keep it in mind as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS. Azure data factory copy activity doesn’t support ftp as sink.

Comment: How would I use SSIS? Using a single C# script to connect to both Blob Storage and FTP to transfer files?